# Calling php scripts inside ruby code

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I want to call a php scripts from my ruby code. From ruby it needs to pass the arguments to php as command line arguments. But for argument with spaces it is treating it as command.

For example:

```
result = 'php sample.php "#{name}" "#{location}"'
```

It is returning

```
sh: line 1: Blahh Blahh: command not found
sh: line 2: Some more Blahh: command not found
```

Can anyone tell how to pass ruby string as argument??

Comment: Not sure why this user was downvoted.

Comment: The *question* was downvoted, not the user. @DickieBoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the backticks syntax to make system calls.

But the issue is really that you need to pass the `-f` option to PHP to tell PHP to execute a file instead of trying to run the command line arguments.

**test.rb:**

```
path = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/'
args = ['arg1', 'arg2']
puts `php -f #{ path + 'sample.php'} { args.join(' ') }`
```

**sample.php**

```
<?php 
if (isset($argv)){
 print_r($argv);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./sample.php
    [1] => arg1
    [2] => arg2
)
```

**Edit**

You can also use the StdLib component [Shellwords](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) to escape and quote the arguments for you:

```
require 'shellwords'
path = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/'
args = ['arg1', 'arg2 asdas']
puts `php -e #{ path + 'test.php'} #{ Shellwords.join(args) }`
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./test.php
    [1] => arg1
    [2] => arg2 asdas
)
```